# Distinct List of Values from XML child elements using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, distinct-values

I have XML as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Set>
<Bundles>
    <BundleID>1</BundleID>
    <BundleDetails>
        <Classification>A</Classification>
        <TrackingID>34675</TrackingID>
    </BundleDetails>
    <BundleQty>12</BundleQty>
</Bundles>
<Bundles>
    <BundleID>2</BundleID>
    <BundleDetails>
        <Classification>B</Classification>
        <TrackingID>4563</TrackingID>
    </BundleDetails>
    <BundleDetails>
        <Classification>A</Classification>
        <TrackingID>4563</TrackingID>
    </BundleDetails>
    <BundleQty>34</BundleQty>
</Bundles>
<Bundles>
    <BundleID>3</BundleID>
    <BundleDetails>
        <Classification>A</Classification>
        <TrackingID>2343243</TrackingID>
    </BundleDetails>
    <BundleQty>22</BundleQty>
</Bundles>
<Bundles>
    <BundleID>4</BundleID>
    <BundleDetails>
        <Classification>A</Classification>
        <TrackingID>123231</TrackingID>
    </BundleDetails>
    <BundleDetails>
        <Classification>B</Classification>
    </BundleDetails>
    <BundleDetails>
        <Classification>B</Classification>
        <TrackingID>42342</TrackingID>
    </BundleDetails>
    <BundleQty>33</BundleQty>
</Bundles>
<Bundles>
    <BundleID>5</BundleID>
    <BundleDetails>
        <Classification>A</Classification>
        <TrackingID>123231</TrackingID>
    </BundleDetails>
    <BundleDetails>
        <Classification>A</Classification>
        <TrackingID>42342</TrackingID>
    </BundleDetails>
    <BundleDetails>
        <Classification>B</Classification>
        <TrackingID>124512</TrackingID>
    </BundleDetails>
    <BundleQty>21</BundleQty>
</Bundles>
</Set>
```

I need to get details for each Set/Bundles as below

```
Bundle# Qty  Classes
1      12      A
2      34      A,B
3      22      A
4      33     A,B
5      21     A,B
```

I started as below, But struck at getting distinct list of classes. Need some guidance,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <p>Set Details</p>
  <table>
       <xsl:for-each select="Set/Bundles">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="BundleID"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="BundleQty"/></td>
          <td>--Distinct List of ./BundleDetails/Classification </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Appreciate your help in advance!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kClassByValAndGrParent" match="Classification"
  use="concat(generate-id(../..),'+', .)"/>

 <xsl:template match="*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Bundle#</th><th>Qty</th><th>Classes</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Bundles">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::BundleDetails)]"/>
   <td>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "BundleDetails/Classification
                      [generate-id()
                      =
                       generate-id(key('kClassByValAndGrParent',
                                        concat(generate-id(../..),'+', .)
                                      )[1]
                                  )
                      ]
      "/>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="BundleID|BundleQty">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="BundleDetails"/>

 <xsl:template match="Classification">
   <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Set>
    <Bundles>
        <BundleID>1</BundleID>
        <BundleDetails>
            <Classification>A</Classification>
            <TrackingID>34675</TrackingID>
        </BundleDetails>
        <BundleQty>12</BundleQty>
    </Bundles>
    <Bundles>
        <BundleID>2</BundleID>
        <BundleDetails>
            <Classification>B</Classification>
            <TrackingID>4563</TrackingID>
        </BundleDetails>
        <BundleDetails>
            <Classification>A</Classification>
            <TrackingID>4563</TrackingID>
        </BundleDetails>
        <BundleQty>34</BundleQty>
    </Bundles>
    <Bundles>
        <BundleID>3</BundleID>
        <BundleDetails>
            <Classification>A</Classification>
            <TrackingID>2343243</TrackingID>
        </BundleDetails>
        <BundleQty>22</BundleQty>
    </Bundles>
    <Bundles>
        <BundleID>4</BundleID>
        <BundleDetails>
            <Classification>A</Classification>
            <TrackingID>123231</TrackingID>
        </BundleDetails>
        <BundleDetails>
            <Classification>B</Classification>
        </BundleDetails>
        <BundleDetails>
            <Classification>B</Classification>
            <TrackingID>42342</TrackingID>
        </BundleDetails>
        <BundleQty>33</BundleQty>
    </Bundles>
    <Bundles>
        <BundleID>5</BundleID>
        <BundleDetails>
            <Classification>A</Classification>
            <TrackingID>123231</TrackingID>
        </BundleDetails>
        <BundleDetails>
            <Classification>A</Classification>
            <TrackingID>42342</TrackingID>
        </BundleDetails>
        <BundleDetails>
            <Classification>B</Classification>
            <TrackingID>124512</TrackingID>
        </BundleDetails>
        <BundleQty>21</BundleQty>
    </Bundles>
</Set>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>Bundle#</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Classes</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>A</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>B,A</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>A</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>A,B</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>A,B</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use of the **[Muenchian Grouping Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.
2. Proper composite **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** definition specifying any `Classification` as a function of its grand-parent and its string value.

Comment: +1 The only thing I would add is an `xsl:sort` to the `xsl:apply-templates` for `Classification`.

Comment: @DevNull, Thanks, and you are right. As the `Bundles` appear already sorted by `BundleID`, I didn't bother to add any sorting. We could even suppose that there could be more than one `Bundles` with the same `BundleID` and then we should add another level of grouping, but this goes too far away from the real XML document.